# Angular Carousel in Cordova Just Not Working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, angular-carousel

I'm trying to make a little slideshow on this app I'm working on.  It is built in Cordova with Angular for iOS.

Here is the relevant code.

```
$scope.images = [{src: 'img/gcPreview0.png'},
{src: 'img/gcPreview1.png'},
{src: 'img/gcPreview2.png'},
{src: 'img/gcPreview3.png'},
{src: 'img/gcPreview4.png'},
{src: 'img/gcPreview5.png'}];
```

I've tried several version of below:

```
        <ul rn-carousel class="image">
          <li ng-repeat="image in images" 
                            style="background-image:url({{ image.src }});">
            <div class="layer">image #{{ $index }}</div>
          </li>
         </ul>
```

I can get my images to show with ng-repeat, but for some reason the directive isn't going live.  I get no error message, of course, and everything that's supposed to be installed is installed (ngTouch, angular-carousel).
A console.log shows that the directive itself is being called in angular-carousel.

Anyone know something I don't about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your using angular 1.4, this could be the issue.

https://github.com/revolunet/angular-carousel/issues/338

Comment: That's great, I managed to get the carousel to sort of work! Apparently height has to be set to a fixed height manually.  Weird.